# How do I maintain a pointer to a List in a Java class?

Tags: java, list

I have a very simple Java class:

```
public class Party {
    private List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String headHost = null;

    public void addHost(String name) {
        hosts.add(name);
        headHost = name;
    }
}
```

But it seems a bit silly to maintain a String keeping track of the list's pointer...

**1. Is there a better way for keeping track of who is the "head host"?**

It won't always be the last person added, either:

```
public void setHost(int i) {
    headHost = hosts.get(i); // potentially throws an exception based on i
}

public void setHost(String name) {
    headHost = name;
}
```

**2. What's the best way to change the current "head host"? Both of these methods could potentially take incorrect parameters.**

Comment: I think current version is good. Just add validation to `setHost` methods.

Comment: Thanks, it was a shot in the dark that there was a more compact version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version is just fine. If you are concerned about exceptions, you can apply some defensive programming to the code:

```
public void setHost(int i) {
    if(i < 0 || i > hosts.size()-1){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index is out of range!");
    }
    headHost = hosts.get(i);
}

public void setHost(String name) {
    if(!hosts.contains(name){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified host does not exist.");
    }
    headHost = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` **doesn't have a concept of current**, at least not in Java. If you want to know what the first element is, just use `List.get(0)`

To get the last element, use `hosts.get(hosts.size()-1)`.

You may also be interested in the [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class, which has **LIFO** (last in, first out) methods to make it even easier to get the most recently entered element.

If for some reason you want to be able to lookup a `host` by `String name`, don't use a `List`, use a `Map` (preferably a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html))

Comment: Thanks - I understand how to access the list at a specific point, I was mostly looking for some sort of pointer to accompany the list.

Comment: Are you writing a new class like `class ListWithPointer<E> implements List<E>`?

Comment: I wasn't going to because it seems like overkill but that's essentially the idea.

Comment: [`List#listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29) is kind of a pointer to a current item in a `List`

Answer (score 1):

You area already holding just a pointer.  String is an object in java.

When you do this:

```
public void addHost(String name) {
    hosts.add(name);
    headHost = name;
}
```

There is only one string with two pointers to it, one pointer in the list and one in your instance variable headHost.  There are not two copies of the actual data.